# How is the minimum number of TDRS satellites needed for a space station program?

Tags: orbital-mechanics, rockets, spacecraft, space-shuttle, crewed-spaceflight

What is the minimum number of retransmission satellites that you would need to assist your LEO space station program - to provide a full time coverage to ensure a total communication with the space station, thus avoiding the use of ground-based antennas to communicate directly with the spacecraft? I guess that 2 GEO satellites, on oposite sides of Earth, would be enough. Any ideas? (green square - launch site; black dot - space station)[image: green- launch site. the two satellites are on each side]

Comment: Related (not a duplicate of): [Minimum number of satellites to image the entirety of Earth's surface at all times](http://space.stackexchange.com/q/8414/49) and [How can the optimal number of satellites in an orbital plane be determined?](http://space.stackexchange.com/q/1081/49) Can you please [edit] to explain what you mean with _... total communication, avoiding the use of ground-based antennas_? Communication with what? For direct line of sight comms between two sats, they just need to be co-orbital with a phase angle difference less than 180° minus half the angular diameter of the Earth.

Answer (score 4):

The configuration you've drawn is almost enough. Both satellites must be able to reach the ground station, so you need to move the ground station (or the satellites) a bit.